# Function `f` has no implicit type when passed as an argument to Fortran subroutine

Tags: fortran

I have a problem correctly passing a function as an argument to a subroutine.

I initially wrote the program in a single .f90 file, but I had to switch to CodeBlocks, and therefore needed to split my modules to separate files. I've encountered an error that I don't think existed before the split:

The program uses a module named "diff_eq.f90", which in turn calls for a subroutine named "find_root". This subroutine resides in a different module named "roots.f90".

The module "diff_eq" calls "find_roots" via:

```
module diff_eq
contains
  function solve_star([bunch of arguments]) result(r)
    use roots
    real(8) :: r,[bunch of arguments]
    call find_root(f,df,[bunch of arguments])
  end function solve_star
end module diff_eq
```

The arguments "f, df" are functions that are defined in yet another module named "wdstar.f90". For example, the declaration for "f" is

```
function f(r)
  real(8),intent(in) :: r(:)
  real(8) :: f(size(r))
  integer :: i,n
  real(8) :: dns(size(r)),prs(size(r))

  [bunch of calculations f(n) = ...]

end function f
```

and the program itself contains all declarations:

```
use diff_eq
use roots
use wdstar
```

Finally, "find_root" declares these functions via:

```
subroutine find_root(f,df,r,[arguments])
    real(8),intent(in out) :: r(n)
    real(8) :: [more arguments]
    interface
       function f(r)
         real(8),intent(in) :: r(:)
         real(8) :: f(size(r))
       end function f
       function df(r)
         real(8),intent(in) :: r(:)
         real(8) :: df(size(r),size(r))
       end function df
    end interface

    [bunch o' calcs]

    end subroutine find_root
```

My question is: what is the proper way to pass these functions to "find_root"?

At the moment I get an error: `Symbol "f" has no IMPLICIT type`

Comment: Why obviously? If it is obvious, why do you ask here? What is the **complete** output? Does the compiler report a code line whrere the error happens?

Comment: @VladimirF I apologize for the choice of words. I did some reading before asking here and I undertand that the things need to be explicitly defined a type or otherwise sometimes receive some default type. So I understand why there should be some type to assign to the functions, but I don't understand what it should be.

Comment: You mean the complete output for the error? And the compiler reports the error on the "call find_root(f,df,[bunch of arguments])" line in "solve_star" function

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any declaration of `f` in `diff_eq`. (If there is one, please show it.)

If `f` it is external, declare it as such. Or use the appropriate module where `f` resides if it is in a module.

You are probably just missing `use wdstar` but you show only small parts of the code so I am not sure.